# How can I create a range of times incremented by fifteen minutes with RxJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to create an array of times with RxJS operators using Moment.js objects. I think the `generate()` operator would be well suited, but it's returning the same time over and over, instead of the incremented time. What am I doing wrong?

According to the docs,

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/generate

I should be able to use `generate(startingValue, condition, increment)` to create an observable which I can then pipe or subscribe to, but I can't get this to work.

```
times(): void {
        const startTime: Moment = START.clone(); //2019-01-01T16:00:00.000
        const endTime: Moment = END;             //2019-01-01T21:00:00.000
        generate(startTime, time => time <= endTime, time => time.add(15, 'minutes')).pipe(
           toArray()
        ).subscribe(console.log);
}

// returns: [2019-01-01T16:00:00.000, 2019-01-01T16:00:00.000...] 20 times
// desired: [2019-01-01T16:00:00.000, 2019-01-01T16:15:00.000, 2019-01-01T16:30:00.000... ]
```

I'm just getting an array of 20 moment objects, all with the same time value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used `generate()` but it is possible that the problem is in the fact that the `moment` object is mutable so that `momentObject.add(...)` changes the `momentObject`. See here: https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/mutability/

You could try:
`generate(startTime, time => time <= endTime, time => time.clone().add(15, 'minutes'))`

Comment: Don't you need to clone as you progress, rather than just at the start?

Comment: You were right, I don't know why it didn't work the first time I tried it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need RxJs to create an array? Why not just use Array.from? RxJs creates streams, not arrays.

```js
const createDateRange = (start, end, intervalQuantity, intervalType) => {
  const duration = moment.duration(end.diff(start));
  const interval = moment.duration(intervalQuantity, intervalType);
  return Array.from(
    { length: (duration.asHours() / interval.asHours()) + 1 },
    (_, i) => start.clone().add(moment.duration(intervalQuantity * i, intervalType))
  );
};

console.log(
  createDateRange(
    moment('2019-01-01T16:00:00.000'),
    moment('2019-01-01T21:00:00.000'),
    15,
    'minutes'
  )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you then want an observable you could wrap the array with of to emit the whole array or from to emit the values one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My question specifically concerns RxJS because I'm trying to accomplish a traditionally imperative task in a functional/reactive way. Also, I may be wrong but it seems like the solution you provided is generating times from the end onward as opposed to the interval between the start and end.

Comment: Times are being displayed in UTC that is what Z at the end means, 2019-01-01T16:00:00.000 is displayed as 2019-01-01T06:00:00.000Z for me. They are the same as I am in a +10 timezone.

Comment: Array.from may not be reactive but it is purely functional.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I was not confused by the 'Z' (as I am familiar with UTC), but why your code snippet generates times from the 'end' parameter onwards. So, for me, I am seeing a range from `2019-01-01T21:00:00.000Z` to `2019-01-02T02:00:00.000Z` on the following date. Maybe the intention wasn't clear from my question, but I was looking to generate time intervals _between_ the 'start' and 'end' parameters. 21:00:00.000 was the **upper** boundary. In any case, I was hoping to get help with the **RxJS** implementation as I have described. Thanks anyway for trying.